# Is there an ADB command to enable/disable mobile data?(Not Rooted Device)

Tags: connection, automated-tests, adb, appium, state

Is there an ADB command to enable/disable mobile data?(Not Rooted Device) ?

I need this for automation test , so java only.

I saw this :

`adb shell am broadcast -a io.appium.settings.wifi --es setstatus disable`

at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/io.appium.settings

And this simply does nothing but will return :

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=io.appium.settings.wifi (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

And i saw some people using :

```
adb shell svc data enable
```

but this will work only on rooted devices .

Any idea ?

By the way , i am searching for ADB command solution after the Android Driver methods are failed .

Comment: You could [drop all the packets it's sending](https://discuss.appium.io/t/is-it-possible-to-simulate-the-network-data-connection/2855/2)

Answer (score 1):

I think a good solution might be to enable and disable again airplane mode... But maybe wont fit with what you are looking for...

Anyway try:

```
adb shell settings put global airplane_mode_on 1 // 1 turn on airplane mode, 0 turn off airplane mode
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE
```

Comment: Beside airPlane mode is there a way to control the other data (WIFI,4G)

Comment: Not exactly but it did lead me to the solution !! thanks a lot

Comment: We cant always have it the way we want haha. Your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Open wifi settings :

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.wifi.WifiSettings
```

making sure the first selector it selected :

```
adb shell input keyevent 19
```

pressing on it (switch)

```
  adb shell input keyevent 23
```

Comment: These may work but not on all Android devices. (I tried and worked with one of three)